# Front page elements not displayed correctly

Tags: views

I have recently uploaded my local site to the hosting server
and since then I have had seen front page element displayed
incorrectly. I have a views slideshow assigned to the front page
and that is where elements are missing. When I click on the home
link on the website, everything is displayed correctly.

I occasionally get the error:

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 83 of 108 bytes in variable_initialize() (line 935 of /home/ebemorgi/kog.church/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

I am not sure  whether the above error has got something to do with
the problem. Also, initially I had a problem  with clean urls and then
I have uploaded the .htaccess that ships with drupal.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit**: The problem usually happens with firefox.

Comment: What is missing? Images?

Comment: Images inside the slideshow are not always fully loaded and sometimes the slideshow panels overlaps..

Comment: I encountered same problem with Bootstrap Grid views format on Chrome. But image is appearing after click on it. Did you try to remake your view?

Comment: Remake in the sense? Build the same view from scratch?

Comment: Yes, same view from scratch. Or duplicate existing, mb it will work